# Evenly space circles along sin curve

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to position sprites (visually circlular with, say radius 50) evenly along a sin curve.

Currently, the function I am using for x and y are:

```
for(int i=0; i<number_of_sprites; i++){
    x = sprite_index*60
    y = sin(sprite_index)*60

    sprite.position = CGPointMake(x, y)
}
```

Even though the sprites are all evenly spaced along the x axis, you are not all equidistant from each other.

This is somewhat pseudocode - I'm simply looking for the mathematical function to do this.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `y = Math.sin(sprite_index*60);`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sin.asp

Comment: This is a hard problem - see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45089/what-is-the-length-of-a-sine-wave-from-0-to-2-pi

Comment: and I suggest you work with `Math.PI` inside your sine function to get workable results

Comment: @myfunkyside the OP said this was pseudo-code - the actual math involved in calculating points that are equidistant _along the arc of the curve_ is pretty difficult.

Comment: my bad:) ..still, if he chooses to use `60` in his pseudo-code, he might as well use `Math.sin` and `PI` to let us know he's aware of their existence

Comment: This question is somewhat vague: do you want to the arc-length between each point to be equal, or the strait line distance?

Answer (score 7):

According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45089/what-is-the-length-of-a-sine-wave-from-0-to-2-pi) on math.stackexchange.com, the solution for calculating the arc length along a sine wave is an *elliptic integral* which is difficult to calculate analytically.

Fortunately you have a computer at your disposal that can apply the same formula using numerical integration to achieve an *approximation* of the desired curve.

Given the derivative of `sin(x)` is `cos(x)`, if you increment your `x` variable very slowly (with a per-step increment of `dx`) then at each step your `ds` will be `dx * sqrt(1 + cos(x)^2)`.  Keep accumulating the `ds` values until it reaches (or exceeds) your desired spacing and only then draw a point.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/fp7aknoc/ for a demo.

Comment: I cannot spot the mistake, but it doesn't seem to do well at producing really equidistant points: http://jsfiddle.net/fp7aknoc/13/. Can it be a numerical floating-point issue?

Comment: The problem seems to be taking `Math.sqrt` from very small values. I'm getting better results with just omitting it: http://jsfiddle.net/fp7aknoc/14/

Comment: @Bergi it's supposedly generating points that are equidistant _along the curve_ and not in simple cartesian distance.  I know what you mean about the apparent effect - the points along the "straight" lines still look further apart than those nearer the peaks, but the fact that the total distance correctly comes out at 7.6404 makes me confident that it's correct.

Comment: Surely the curve might be a bit longer than the cartesian distance, but that much? I would expect the approximation to be quite good.

Comment: @Bergi : (As this was linked to from another recent post) The problem was that you computed the points for `y=sin(x)` but applied them to a graph of `y=sin(pi/5*x)` by using different scale factors in x and y directions. If you correct that for instance by setting `var px = 90 * x; var py = 200 - 90 * fx;` using equal scaling, the circles are evenly arranged along the graph.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two constraints. Given a point `a`, a radius `r`, and a function `f`, you need to find a point `b` s.t.

```
Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a.x - b.x, 2) + Math.pow(a.y - b.y, 2)) === 2r
```

AND

```
f(b.x) == b.y
```

The first condition ensures that the two points are exactly non-overlapping, and the second ensures that b is on the curve you want (in this case, I think this function is `Math.sin`).

You need to do a bit of algebra to arrive at the solution, but this is how I'd set up this problem.

Comment: your math is incorrect - even if it were correct (and solvable) it would only give points that are the straight line distance `r` apart - this does not measure the distance _along the curve_.

Comment: "spaced evenly" along the curve is ambiguous. These points are both spaced evenly and along the curve :P. Where did I make a mistake in the math?

Comment: @Alnitak this is now fixed.

Comment: Given: "Even though the sprites are all evenly spaced along the x axis, you are not all equidistant from each other", I think this kind of solution is exactly what is called for.

Comment: the question is indeed a little ambiguous on what "distance" is being measured.