# Evaluate function at constant speed relative to arc length

Tags: function, math, polynomial-math

I'm implementing a realtime graphics engine (C++ / OpenGL) that moves a vehicle over time along a specified course that is described by a polynomial function. The function itself was programmatically generated outside the application and is of a high order (I believe >25), so I can't really post it here (I don't think it matters anyway). During runtime the function does not change, so it's easy to calculate the first and second derivatives once to have them available quickly later on.

My problem is that I have to move along the curve with a constant speed (say 10 units per second), so my function parameter is not equal to the time directly, since the arc length between two points x1 and x2 differs dependent on the function values. For example the difference f(a+1) - f(a) may be way larger or smaller than f(b+1) - f(b), depending on how the function looks at points a and b.

I don't need a 100% accurate solution, since the movement is only visual and will not be processed any further, so any approximation is OK as well. Also please keep in mind that the whole thing has to be calculated at runtime each frame (60fps), so solving huge equations with complex math may be out of the question, depending on computation time.

I'm a little lost on where to start, so even any train of thought would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do you know any calculus?   The angle at which you need to move the vehicle is the first differential of the polynomial.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226663/evenly-space-circles-along-sin-curve/26226795#26226795

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that approach. However I'm probably going to have to adapt it slightly, since the people in the linked math.stackexchange page seemed to have trouble with sqrt's precision and small numbers (I too am working with rather small numbers here).

Comment: Another idea that you gave me is that I might try just literally setting the rotation of the object according to the first derivative and then pushing it along in a straight vector with a certain length. (however that might me even more un-precise)

Comment: FWIW, I'd probably use the first derivative to calculate the movement vector's `dx` and `dy` components, but then plug the resulting `x + dx` into your original polynomial to ensure that the resulting point ends up on the curve.    (working on the basis that the accuracy of the coordinate on that curve is more important than strict accuracy w.r.t. the velocity)

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that as well! After all it's just for looks and I'll probably go with what feels more natural when animated (However I'm still a little far away from that).

Comment: In my first comment, I did of course mean that the _slope_ at which you need to move is the first derivative.  (not the _angle_)

Comment: @Markus: There was no problem with `sqrt`, there was a problem with non-isometric scaling which of course distorts distances and their relations. With equal scales in all directions, the linked approach works perfectly in both versions, with differences and differentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the criterion was not to have an exact solution, but a visually appealing approximation, there were multiple possible solutions to try out.

---

The **first** approach (suggested by Alnitak in the comments and later answered by coproc) I implemented, which is approximating the actual arclength integral by tiny iterations. This version worked really well most of the time, but was not reliable at really steep angles and used too many iterations at flat angles. As coproc already pointed out in the answer, a possible solution would be to base dx on the second derivative.

All these adjustments *could* be made, however, I need a runtime friendly algorithm. With this one it is hard to predict the number of iterations, which is why I was not happy with it.

---

The **second** approach (also inspired by Alnitak) is utilizing the first derivative by "pushing" the vehicle along the calculated slope (which is equal to the derivative at the current x value). The function for calculating the next x value is really compact and fast. Visually there is no obvious inaccuracy and the result is always consistent. (That's why I chose it)

```
float current_x = ...; //stores current x
float f(x) {...}
float f_derv(x) {...}

void calc_next_x(float units_per_second, float time_delta) {
  float arc_length = units_per_second * time_delta;
  float derv_squared = f_derv(current_x) * f_derv(current_x);
  current_x += arc_length / sqrt(derv_squared + 1);
}
```

This approach, however, will possibly only be accurate enough for cases with high frame time (mine is >60fps), since the object will always be pushed along a straight line with a length depending on said frame time.

Answer (score 0):

Given the constant speed and the time between frames the desired arc length between frames can be computed. So the following function should do the job:

```
#include <cmath>
typedef double (*Function)(double);

double moveOnArc(Function f, const double xStart, const double desiredArcLength, const double dx = 1e-2)
{
  double arcLength = 0.;
  double fPrev = f(xStart);
  double x = xStart;
  double dx2 = dx*dx;
  while (arcLength < desiredArcLength)
  {
    x += dx;
    double fx = f(x);
    double dfx = fx - fPrev;
    arcLength += sqrt(dx2 + dfx*dfx);
    fPrev = fx;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Since you say that accuracy is not a top criteria, choosing an appropriate `dx` the above function might work right away. Ofcourse, it could be improved by adjusting `dx` automatically (e.g. based on the second derivative) or by refining the endpoint with a binary search.